# Check if File has been modified in time in C#

Tags: c#, timer, last-modified

I have an application that reads a file every 5 minutes. When the program starts, it reads the file and as soon as it completes it starts a timer. As soon as the 5 minutes passes, the timer stops and reads the file again.

I would like to check if the file has been modified in that time period, if it is not, it does not read the file.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
DateTime dtFile = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

long sub = (long)(now - dtFile).TotalMilliseconds;

if(sub <= timer1.Interval)
{
    // the code goes here
}
```

My problem is that my process has multiple files to read, then the process can take several minutes.

Therefore, if the first file finishes execution at 10:00 am and the processing of all files ends at 10:05 am, the timer will start at 10:05 am.
So the timer will stop at 10:10 am.

If the first read file is modified at 10:02 am, it will not be read because the timer started running at the end of full processing at 10:05 am. So, the modified file at 10:02 am will be out of period.

Comment: An alternative to polling the files every 5 minutes could be to _react_ to changes using the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Please don't assume your audience is entirely male here, that can sometimes have an exclusionary effect on some of your readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its just one way to do it but i suggest doing it like this.
Create a new class containing following properties:
- a public string, for the path to the file
- a datetime , to store the last check time
- a timer object

Now create a constructor defining the path, start time and to define and enable the timer.

On application start or whenever you can instatiate one object for each file now. Each object will have an independent timer now so the wont interfere whit eachother anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I thought of making a class containing a string from the file path and a Datetime with the date of the last modification. Then when the general timer was run again, I would check if the last modification of the file is different from the date it is in the class. Would it work? The problem would instantiate the class for more than 100 files, because it would end up weighing the application.